# Can I integrate BIDS with SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, business-intelligence

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2. Now I want to install BIDS in this SQL Server. Can I install it from this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=3C856B93-369F-4C6F-9357-C35384179543&displaylang=en

Is this going to work? Thank you!

Comment: That link goes to a **2005** version, and no, as far as I can tell, that does not concern BIDS at all. BIDS should be on your installation DVD - one of the options when you install SQL Server itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIDS is part of the SQL Server Client Tools which will be visible as one of the options when you try and install SQL Server. There is no real need to install it on the server as you can connect remotely.

You can see it [here](http://blogs.mvp-press.com/Portals/1/SunBlogNuke/5/Windows-Live-Writer/InstallandConfigureSQLServer2008FirstLoo_27D7/9_Install%20SQL%20-%20Feature%20Selection_thumb.png) under 'shared features'. Just select that and untick all the other options when running it on the machine on which you wish to install it.

Answer (score 0):

BIDS is not installed on the SQL Server.  It is a development environment that uses Visual Studio.  You can install BIDS from your SQL Server 2008R2 installation media, but you can also get the express 2005 version from your link.  You should be able to connect to your SQL Server using either approach.

Comment: BIDS isn't included with express I thought?

Comment: @ajdams, It does have the SSRS development I think.  OP isn't clear whether SSIS or SSRS is needed.  You make a good point though.  If SSIS is required, you must use the SQL Server 2008R2 install.